# Joomla front end has no content after web server move

Tags: joomla

I am so stumped with this and I need some help from the community. I moved my joomla site over to a new server and now the content has disappeared from the front end, I am not getting an errors.... Can someone offer any suggestions on where to look for the problem? my config is fine and I am pretty sure my database is aswell because all my original articles are there.

I am running Joomla 1.5

The URL: http://www.davidjamesmedia.ca

Answer (score 0):

If you moved to a new server at a different hosting company, Joomla is probably either

- not looking in the right place for the database, or
- not using the right credentials (host, port, username, password, whatever) for the database.

That might also be true if you moved to a different server at the same hosting company, although it's a *little* less likely.  Look at the configuration.php file.

Assuming you have shell access, make sure you can access the database through its command-line utility.  Then make sure Joomla is using the same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really odd one.

The database credentials are obviously correct otherwise the site wouldn't load at all and would result in a MySQL error. Try re-assigning a new temporary article to the homepage else download the [K2](http://getk2.org/) component, import your articles and assign the K2 article to the homepage.

**Update:**

If you have the demo package for the template you are using the follow these steps:

1. create a sub domain
2. install the demo package with sample data
3. export the `#__content` database table from the main website
4. replace the `#__content` table with the one you exported

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work, the module positions are set, the content is assigned to the positions, its just not rendering content or menus in their desired locations

Comment: @onei0120 - I have updated my answer with a new suggestion. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your error reporting is on in your server's php.ini file so that you can see what errors php is giving i.e. `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel, can you see the articles in content menu?

If so, enter in each article and push the Save button.
After you save the article, it should appear again in frontpage (that worked for me).